# react-dom render: direct module import

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Is there a way to do a direct module import for ReactDOM's `render` method to minimize bundle size?

For example, this direct module import works for `findDOMNode`:

```
import findDOMNode from 'react-dom/lib/findDOMNode';
```

...but this does not:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount';
```

Comment: Looks like `ReactMount` exports an object versus `findDOMNode` which exports a function. `render` is a function within `ReactMount` but you can't access is like that. In short, I think it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

Worked for me.

Comment: What you're showing is a destructured import, not a direct module import. The question is a bit outdated; the proper way to handle this now is with [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Comment: @cantera can you tell me how we can import render method from react-dom module without using destructuring, meaning as a direct module.